# Running exponential decay model in R

Tags: model, regression, exponential, nls, decay

> Concentration<-c(6.2,6.1,5,4.9,3.7,3.8,3.8,3.9,3.6,3.5,3.9,3.6)
> Distance<-c(5,5,15,15,25,25,32,32,42,42,55,55)
> b0start <- max(Concentration)
> b1start <- -log(1/b0start)
> b2start <- (max(Concentration) - min(Concentration)) / (max(Distance) - min(Distance)) / b0start
> mystart<-c(b0=b0start,b1=b1start,b2=b2start)
> model_exponential <- nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), data = Concentration, start = list(a = 0, b = 1))
> Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), data = Concentration, start = list(a = 0,  :
> 'data' must be a list or an environment

I want to run an exponential decay model for Distance and Cconcentration but it is giving an error

> Concentration<-c(6.2,6.1,5,4.9,3.7,3.8,3.8,3.9,3.6,3.5,3.9,3.6)
> Distance<-c(5,5,15,15,25,25,32,32,42,42,55,55)
> b0start <- max(Concentration)
> b1start <- -log(1/b0start)
> b2start <- (max(Concentration) - min(Concentration)) / (max(Distance) - min(Distance)) / b0start
> mystart<-c(b0=b0start,b1=b1start,b2=b2start)
> model_exponential <- nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), data = Concentration, start = list(a = 0, b = 1))
> Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), data = Concentration, start = list(a = 0,  :
> 'data' must be a list or an environment

Comment: How is _Concentration_ related to _x_ or _y_?